# The Problems List is not Populated successfully in the Get Level API

Tags: mysql, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, domain-model

Using .NET Core and EF Im trying to make a list of level for all level it has some problems
when I create the problem and the level and then add the problem to the level Using an Api that I create I have this as response
[image]

which exactly like i want

but when I try to get the level itself i dont have the problems list populated

[image]

in the Database I have the problem is refernced with the levelID but cant find the problem list in the Level TABLE in DB However I added it to the Domain Model in the Code

Please find the pictures below

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eager load Problems when reading your Level using `.Include(x => x.Problems)`.

Also initialize your List of problems either on declaration

```
public List<Problem> Problems { get; private set;} = new();
```

... or in the constructor, not ad-hoc when accessed. With collections you should ensure they are initialized once, and protect their setters to avoid misuse which will muck up EF if abused.